# Problem setting up HP PhotoSmart C4783

Tags: wireless-networking, printer, network-printer

I am trying to get several PC's on a network to connect to my client's new wireless printer, the C4783.  I initially installed the whole HP 'tsumami of software' the comes with the printer onto my laptop, connected to the printer over USB, and corrected it's networking config.  My laptop now also can connect to and print on the printer over the wireless network, as is intended for all PC's.

However, when I try and install the HP software on my client's netbook, the HP software cannot find the printer.  Firewall was turned off during this time, so doesn't play a role.  I tried re-installing all software, but I initially only got a "Repair" or "Uninstall".  Choosing Uninstall triggers a lengthy process that ends with a sudden and forceful restart, after which the same "Repair" or "Uninstall" choices are present.  Looks like uninstall doesn't.

Any suggestions as to how I can begin diagnosing why my laptop has no problem connecting to the printer, but two others do?  Wireless is unsecured, and no, nobody has to know where I am right now. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Look through the help to see if the HP software supports wireless connectivity. It could just be that the program isn't looking for printers on the network.

Windows will let you use a printer without any of the printers software as long as you have the drivers. Which is why it's showing up on the network yet it may not be part of the HP software package.

*Sorry, poor explantion.*

Comment: The package is bundled with the printer, it would be huge fail if it didn't support it.  It does support it, used from my machine to configure the printer, over wireless

Comment: Not a poor explanation at all, though you could have added how to add printers without using the HP software package. (start control panel printers add create LPR port IP_assigned to printer in your DHCP reservation, ....  that kind of thing).

Answer (score 1):

Well, first we need to establish that the computer you are trying to install the software on can see the printer. Use something like [Angry IP](http://www.angryip.org/w/Home) to verify this from the computer you would like to connect from.

Second, "Firewall was turned off during this time, so doesn't play a role" isn't correct. I have seen scenarios where the "turned off" firewall was still blocking access. Fortunately, step one will start to diagnose this as well.

Based on what information you gave, I would suspect the firewall, so try uninstalling it. If the firewall is bundled together with the antivirus and you're afraid of the security exposure, download AVAST, disconnect computer from Internet, uninstall firewall, install AVAST, reconnect computer.